# jQuery Mobile show() and hide() Don't Work in Android

Tags: android, jquery, show-hide

I am trying to get a "Please wait..." message to display when I make an ajax call to get information.  Basically, the user puts in their search term, hits Search, I want to display "Please wait..." while the page is doing the ajax call, then hide it once it is done.

I have a div on my jsp page that looks like this:

```
<div id="modalWindow">Please Wait...</div>
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
jQuery('#modalWindow').css({
    'text-align' : 'center',
    'font-size' : '20px'
}).hide();  //this is called when the page initially loads

jQuery('#modalWindow').show();    //I call this in the function that does the Ajax call

jQuery('#modalWindow').hide();    //I call this once the Ajax is done.
```

This is my entire Ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax(
{
    url : urlContext + "/getItems.html",
    data :
    {
        txtItemReference : txtItemReference
    },
    dataType : "json",
    cache : false,
    async : false,
    timeout : 100000,
    success : function(jsonResponse)
    {
        if ( jsonResponse instanceof Object)
        {
            if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(jsonResponse))
            {
                createLocationDisplayPanel(false);
                createSimilarItemsPanel(false);
            }
            else if (jsonResponse['Locations'] != undefined)
            {
                responseArray = new Array();
                arrayStart = 0;
                intPage = 1;

                if (jsonResponse['Locations'].length <= 20)
                {
                    for (var x = arrayStart; x < jsonResponse['Locations'].length; x++)
                    {
                        responseArray[x] = jsonResponse['Locations'][x];
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    responseArray = new Array();

                    for (var x = arrayStart; x < (20 * intPage); x++)
                    {
                        responseArray[x] = jsonResponse['Locations'][x];
                    }
                }

                createLocationDisplayPanel(jsonResponse, responseArray, txtItemReference, urlContext, callback);
            }
            else
            {
                if (jsonResponse['Items'].length <= 20)
                {
                    for (var x = arrayStart; x < jsonResponse['Items'].length; x++)
                    {
                        responseArray[x] = jsonResponse['Items'][x];
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    for (var x = arrayStart; x < (20 * intPage); x++)
                    {
                        responseArray[x] = jsonResponse['Items'][x];
                    }
                }

                createSimilarItemsPanel(jsonResponse, responseArray, txtItemReference, urlContext, callback);
            }
            if (callback != undefined)
            {
                callback();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alertLogout(document.URL);
        }
    },
    error : function(jsonResponse)
    {
        if (jsonResponse.hasOwnProperty('ERROR'))
        {
            alertError("There was no response from the server.");
        }
    }
});
```

This works perfectly in Firefox on my desktop as well as Firefox for Android.  However, on every Android browser I've tried, the "Please wait..." text never displays, and I am getting frustrated.  Can anyone please tell me the workaround to get the show() and hide() functions to work in an Android browser?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if jQuery is loaded at that point? Write this before your script.

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    alert('jQuery is not loaded'); 
}
```

You might need to combine the scripts or find a way to ensure they are loaded in the order you need them.

Comment: I tested this. I didn't get that message, so jQuery is in fact loaded.

Comment: Try:
    alert(jQuery('#modalWindow').length);

See if the selector failed. It should be 1.

Comment: As a matter of fact, regular easy changes don't happen in Android.  I tried changing the value of my input box to say "Please wait..." by doing `jQuery('input#txtItemReference').val("Please wait...")` and it still doesn't work.  Works in Firefox, doesn't work in Android...

Comment: It returns 1, so it's there.

Comment: Can you provide your Ajax call? Maybe it is a sync issue?

Comment: I added my entire Ajax call to my original post.

Comment: I don't see the .show() in your success call. Are you sure the .show() is the issue? 
In the success call before the "if" statement, set an alert to confirm it executed correctly. Right after the alert, call .show(). There is a chance that something else is wrong, probably still browser compatibility, but not an issue with jQuery.show()

Comment: My jQuery.show() code is fired when I click the Search button, and it takes place before the actual Ajax call.

Comment: So you set an alert before the .show() to confirm execution flow made it to that point on the click event right?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was with the async property of the Ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax(
{
    url : urlContext + "/getItems.html",
    data :
    {
        txtItemReference : txtItemReference
    },
    dataType : "json",
    cache : false,
    async : true,   //was false before
    timeout : 100000,
    success : function(jsonResponse)
    {
        if ( jsonResponse instanceof Object)
        {
            if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(jsonResponse))
            {
                createLocationDisplayPanel(false);
                createSimilarItemsPanel(false);
            }
            else if (jsonResponse['Locations'] != undefined)
            {
                responseArray = new Array();
                arrayStart = 0;
                intPage = 1;

                if (jsonResponse['Locations'].length <= 20)
                {
                    for (var x = arrayStart; x < jsonResponse['Locations'].length; x++)
                    {
                        responseArray[x] = jsonResponse['Locations'][x];
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    responseArray = new Array();

                    for (var x = arrayStart; x < (20 * intPage); x++)
                    {
                        responseArray[x] = jsonResponse['Locations'][x];
                    }
                }

                createLocationDisplayPanel(jsonResponse, responseArray, txtItemReference, urlContext, callback);
            }
            else
            {
                if (jsonResponse['Items'].length <= 20)
                {
                    for (var x = arrayStart; x < jsonResponse['Items'].length; x++)
                    {
                        responseArray[x] = jsonResponse['Items'][x];
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    for (var x = arrayStart; x < (20 * intPage); x++)
                    {
                        responseArray[x] = jsonResponse['Items'][x];
                    }
                }

                createSimilarItemsPanel(jsonResponse, responseArray, txtItemReference, urlContext, callback);
            }
            if (callback != undefined)
            {
                callback();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alertLogout(document.URL);
        }
    },
    error : function(jsonResponse)
    {
        if (jsonResponse.hasOwnProperty('ERROR'))
        {
            alertError("There was no response from the server.");
        }
    }
});
```

Once I changed that, the show and hide worked in Android.  Thanks for the help guys.